# Reverse tethering of Android device to OSX over WIFI

Tags: macos, wifi, mac-mini, android

or **HOW TO Find OSX wifi sharing on an android device**

I have setup a mac mini (Mountain Lion) with internet sharing to devices using WIFI. My iPhone and iPod both see and can use the connection but none of the Android (Samsung, Nexus 4) can see it.

Any hints as to how I can share the mac mini's internet access with an Android device?

**UPDATE** getting the terminology right seemed to help my search.
Instead of searching on `WIFI Android`, searching on `Ad-Hoc nerwork android` gave me

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1718053

which I will try tomorrow - however I assume this only works if the network is visible

> Step 2 : Configuring the android device :
>
> Now, we will configure the android device to make it able to access this new adhoc network

```
Go to setting on the menu of your device
then wireless and networks then wi-fi settings then activate wi-fi .
Right click and choose advanced .
Check the "Use static IP"and fill in :
ip address: 192.168.137.5 (for example)
Gateway : 192.168.137.1
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
DNS 1: 192.168.137.1
DNS 2 : 172.168.137.1
then right click and save.
```

> Finally, click on the adhoc network (and input password if you use WEP security) then connect.
>       And that's all ...enjoy internet with Google Play download supported...
>       If you encounter problems connecting ,try to disable then to reactivate wifi, else reboot your android device.

Comment: Do you see the network? Are you using the Airport interface?

Comment: No I do not see the network at all from Android but loud and clear from iOS

Answer (score 1):

My only experience with this issue was never resolved as Android at the time did not support ad-hoc networks.  According to [this article](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3372947/connect-android-phone-ad-hoc-network/), you may need to use 3rd-party software.

Comment: Wow - That is pretty sad from an OS the fanboys say can do anything... I'll let the question hang a bit to see more answers

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use WEP encryption? A footnote in Snow-Leopard's setup dialog for sharing over WiFi says:
3

> If you plan to share your Internet connection with non-Apple
>   computers, use a 5 character password for a 40-bit WEP key,
>   and a 13 character password for a 13-bit WEP key.

I just tested this with a Kindle Fire and it does make a difference. With 128-bit WEP and a shorter password it would not connect but connected OK with a 13-character password. I didn't need to set up a static IP or any other special configuration.

Comment: No encryption and I am on Mountain Lion - and I cannot even see the box in the list